# How to Solve Mashup Error in DMG for an Azure Data Factory Pipeline execution

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are connecting the blob storage to the Source on premise systems using a DMG (Data Management Gateway). We are connecting to four sources in the same pipeline. While it connects fine to some if fails for the other (this is totally random) with the following error:
Mashup operation failed at Source side. Error message from Mashup execution : Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) Node Name=DMGUAT-03,ErrorCode=FailedMashupOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message='Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.InternalMashupException,Message=We're sorry, an error occurred during evaluation.,Source=Microsoft.Data.Mashup,''Type=Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException,Message=Access to the path 'MashupSessionCacheMutex_C:_USERS_DIAHOSTSERVICE_APPDATA_LOCAL_TEMP_MICROSOFT_MASHUPPROVIDER_CACHE' is denied.,Source=,',Source=,'.

Tried emptying the cache on the server where the DMG is installed but that did not help.

Can someone please explain the cause and solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Mashup engine are both used in Power BI on-prem data gateway and Data Factory Integration Runtime. Running them at the same time may cause this type of conflict. You could try to separate them into different machines.

Comment: We do not use Power BI on-prem data gatewayinany of our projects. On this machine we have just Data Factory Integration.  Runtime.So no question of separating.

Comment: Could you share which on premise system you are using?

Comment: We are using Sharepoint as the on premise data source.... As yet we are struggling with this issue.

Comment: Any updates? We are specifically getting this with Lists withing Sharepoint.

Comment: It's might be caused by a permission issue that the user account which is used to access SharePoint could not access the cache file folder C:\USERS\DIAHOSTSERVICE\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP. You could try to assign the modify privilege to the user account.